Sum of partial differential operators is self-adjoint on $\mathbb{R}^n$?
Let us consider the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the Cartesian coordinates $x^1, \cdots, x^n$.
For a given $N \in \mathbb{N}$, let $A_1, \cdots, A_n$ be $N \times N$ Hermitian matrices.
Then, I am curious on how to prove that the operator
\begin{equation}
i \sum_{j=1}^n A_j \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}
\end{equation}
is an unbounded densely defined self-adjoint on the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{C}^N)$.
If I remember correctly, each differential operator $i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$ must be self-adjoint on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{C})$ , but I am not sure how to generalize to the above sum.
Could anyone please help me?
